# The Relation btw Clausius' and Boltzmann's Statements of the 2nd Law during a State Change within a Finite Time Interval

Tags: thermodynamics, non-equilibrium

In his book, *Non-Equilibrium Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics*, Attard takes an approach to deduce a relationship between the probability of state (Boltzmann's statement of the 2nd Law) and the probability of transition (Clausius' statement). He considers two situations, the change of state within "a large enough time interval" (or mathematically $\tau \rightarrow \infty $) and within a finite time interval. Some parts are not clear to me in the second situation. Here is the argument:
[image]

Here are my questions and the probable answers I thought of:

What is meant by the "value of the state"? Is he taking one of the    state functions, for example pressure or volume or maybe temperature?

- In the highlighted part, he makes an assumption, but isn't the assumption the idea he is going to show that's true?
- I think it should be $n_{\pm}\propto exp(\frac{S(x)}{k_{B}})$
- what is meant by the "finite width"? Does it show the interval within which the state function can change but macroscopically there is no change of state?
- $x$ in the argument of $n_{+}(x+\frac{\Delta_{x}}{2})$ can only take on the value of the middle of the interval, otherwise the value of the argument will exceed the interval.